# CSS property has been blocked

Tags: html, css

I've builded banner for my home page and I want to hide a few HTML element in the responsive mode. When I run it on chrome browser and then I got an issue. This is css property which has been blocked by another css class. I can't figure it out where this css class is ? Anybody can help me to give me solution?

[image: CSS Inspect Element Image]

Comment: `element.style { }` means inline styles. Probably some JS added it, in this case you should dig up js code, not css, because js will always override whatever you wrote in css file

Comment: its not the *inline CSS*, its due to the ordering of your *responsive CSS*, keep in mind that always include your *Custom CSS* always at the end or after all your *plugin CSS's* to easily customize/alter their look and feel.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay : thank your response but I dont clearly understand about my custom css always at the end or after all your plugin css's to easily customize/alter their look and feel?? Can you reply to me an easily response?

Comment: @Cheslab : thank you so much. I will try to dig up js in my source and I hope I can find it :D

Comment: @KirkDevJr link your *responsive CSS* after that *setting css*

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay okay, thank your suggestion ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I agree with Cheslab, I think this is inline style resulting from javascript.

css with a viewport property will show its source of the top right side of the style section in the console.

Try putting in any css file:

```
img.imgSGHN {display:none;}
```

If this doensn't make any changes, you should be able to override the inline style by adding "!important" (not recommended) in your custom style.

```
img.imgSGHN {display:none!important;}
```

will get rid of .imgSGHN element.

The best way to approach the problem would be finding the script where it creates the inline css style and changing its behavior. Simply making it not override "display: " property will do.

Comment: oh yeah thank your solution very much ... it's worked ;)

Comment: Never encourage anyone to use `!important` its a horrible thing, and apart from that cant you see in the attached image that its not the *inline CSS*, its another *CSS* that overriding the *responsive CSS*.

Comment: You can attach pictures through inline css.  & you won't even need "!important" if the inline css doesn't override display property. Downvote all you like but what's your solution...?